# OpenSuse Leap 42.2 Guest on VMWare Player -> VMware Tools Not working after Restart

Tags: opensuse, vmware-tools

I installed `openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64.iso` as a guest OS on `VMware® Workstation 12 Player 12.5.5` on my Win7 Host System.

`uname -r -> 4.4.27-2-default`

I just clicked "next" on every setup step ( choose KDE Desktop) of Open Suse and I did **NOT** click any button or whatever to install VMware Tools.

After the installation VMware Tools is working ( again without any installation ). I can dragNdrop files etc.

I see the following processes running in my openSUSE:
[image]

I rebooted the machine ( without doing anything after the installatin) and vmware tools is not working anymore.

I still see this processes started after reboot:
[image]

I tried to start "vmtoolsd &" as my local user which leads to the same processes running as in picture one.

Comming from the Windows world I do not understand why vmware-tools is not working anymore.

I also tried to install open-vm-tools like in this [tutorial](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/11/26/how-to-install-vmware-tools-on-opensuse-42-x-leap-32-64bit-linux-easy-guide/) but I could not start it (`vmware-user-suid-wrapper error: could not open proc/fs/vmblock/dev`)

So because the original vmware-tools works every time when I install a new VM ( again its automatically there I did not mount the cd from vmware-tools and installed it ) until I restart, I need help.

Is there something I have to start manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running `/usr/bin/vmtoolsd -n vmusr &` will resolve this.

It seems you've resolved this yourself on de [opensuse forums](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/524213-OpenSuse-Leap-42-2-Guest-on-VMWare-Player-gt-VMware-Tools-Not-working-after-Restart) 
I'm posting your solution here since it helped me.

Comment: Yes this works. It seems that the parameter "`-n vmusr`" did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking if a service is available, using `sudo systemctl status vmtoolsd`, and see if that returns anything (alternatively, try `sudo systemctl list-units | grep tool`).

If you need to enable it, you can run `sudo systemctl start vmtoolsd`, or whatever the appropriate service name is.

According to the [OpenSUSE docs](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:VMware_Tools) for VMWare tools, most of the functionality is in the kernel, so it may also be it isn't a requirement to run the service - that would I think depend on your actual needs.